# Why does text within the divs cause this layout to break?

Tags: html, text, css, border-box

I have the following HTML/CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test script</title>
    <style>
      body, div, html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .outer {
        text-align: center;
      }

      .inner {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 50px;
      }

      .inner div {
        background: red;
        border: #00F solid 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 200px;
        line-height: 200px;
        margin-right: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 200px;
      }

      .inner div:hover {
        border: #0F0 solid 50px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="outer">
      <div class="inner">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

What's really strange is that when you mouse over a div, the change in the border size causes the text within the div to be pushed down as well as the other divs to be pushed down as well.

However, if you remove the text from the divs (i.e., "1", "2", "3" and "4"), then the problem does not occur.

Why does the text within the divs cause the layout to break?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not seeing this difference that you are describing: http://jsfiddle.net/F3STy/ (with text) http://jsfiddle.net/F3STy/1/ (without text)

Comment: @JasonSperske I see it in the fiddles you set up.  I'm using safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch out `display:inline-block;`  with `display:block; float:left;`  it works in safari.

```
body, div, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.outer {
    text-align: center;
}
.inner {
    display:block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    float:left;
}
.inner div {
    background: red;
    border: #00F solid 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    float:left;
    line-height: 200px;

}
.inner div:hover {
    border: #0F0 solid 50px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/hFvPT/

I honestly have no idea why.

Comment: Barbara, you're absolutely right. I simply changed `display: inline-block;` to `float: left;` for the `.inner div` selector, and it worked. Too, too bizarre. I have no clue why either. It must be some property of inline-block that I'm not familiar with. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your line-height. It is set to 200px which is the same as the height of the box, so when you increase the border to 50px you only have room for 100px. One simple fix is to add the lower line-height number to your hover:

```
  .inner div:hover {
    border: #0F0 solid 50px;
    line-height: 100px;
  }
```

**EDIT**

As Barbara Laird has pointed out, this does not actually seem to fix the problem. You could add overflow:hidden to the box and make it work, but it is not pretty. An alternative solution, which also keeps your text vertically centered, would be to add a wrapper and use display:table:

```
  .inner div {
    background: red;
    border: #00F solid 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    display: table;
  }

  .inner div span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/7JH55/

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue in safari.  Even if I remove line-height alltogether from both of them.

Comment: Same. I'm using Chrome (which I should have mentioned in my original post), and removing `line-height` makes no difference whatsoever.